# Angular - Which is the proper way to create a service that retrives data from a server and send them to a component that uses it?

Tags: angular, angular-promise, angular-services

I'm developing a web application using Angular (v6.0.0). I have a server that exposes API to retrive products. Everything works fine, but I'm wondering if what I've done and HOW i did it is correct. If no, I'm wondering if someone can help me improve my code.

Following is my HttpService, which I use as extension of the HttpClient because I have to set used language in the URL of the request:

**HttpService**

```
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private translate: TranslateService
  ) { }

  /**
   * General GET request
   *
   * @param {string} url URL of the request
   * @param {HttpParams} [params]
   * @returns {Promise<any>}
   * @memberof HttpService
   */
  async get(url: string, params?: HttpParams): Promise<any> {
    return await this.http.get<any>(`${environment.apiURL}${this.translate.getDefaultLang()}/${url}`, { params: params }).toPromise();
  }
}
```

Then I have the **ProductService**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from '../http/http.service';
import { Product } from 'src/app/models/product';
import { HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {

  constructor(
    private httpService: HttpService
  ) { }

  async getProductsByCategory(categoryId: string): Promise<Product[]> {
    let res = await this.httpService.get('products', new HttpParams().set('category', categoryId).set('perPage', '1000'));
    return res.data;
  }
}
```

Here note that I know that the products' array is `res.data`.

Now, in the component where I use the `ProductService`, I do the following:

`this.products = await this.productService.getProductsByCategory(ID);`

As I said at the beginning of the question, everything seems to work fine as expected, but I'm getting confused with all the articles I've read about promises and how to use them, so I'd like to ask you guys if this is the proper way to use promises or if I need to improve my code.

Thank you for your responses!

Comment: This question belongs to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) I guess.

Comment: Sorry Sidd, didn't know about CodeReview! Will keep it in mind for the next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you an example code that use in our project.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../../../environments/environment';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { httpOptions } from '../../http-options';
import { Content } from '../../content.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PredefinedContentService {

  private reportPredefinedContentApi = `${environment.baseUrl}/report/report-predefined-contents`;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getList(reportSectionId : number) : Observable<Content[]>{
    return this.httpClient.get<Content[]>(`${this.reportPredefinedContentApi}/${reportSectionId}`, httpOptions);
  }

}
```

In component.ts,

```
reportSectionId: number;
contents: Content[] = [];

constructor(private predefinedTextService: PredefinedContentService) {}

getContentList() {
    this.predefinedTextService
      .getList(this.reportSectionId)
      .subscribe(result => {
        this.contents = result;
        },error => {
           console.log(error)
        });
}
```

Comment: This seems to be very close to my use case! How do you use `getList` in your component?

Comment: Thank you Dhanika! Your answer was very useful! Will mark it as correct answer only because of the example. Anyway, the other answers were useful too!

Comment: Check my answer. I edited that? Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Exactly what I was asking for! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

My only suggestion here will to not use **Promise** because **Observable** can be easily used where you are consuming these services in your code.

Comment: I was googling Observables and found out that this seems to be the next standard, right? But I'm getting a bit confused about that, can't find out any good example

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, your `HttpService` can be converted to a http interceptor. Especially if you only have one API endpoint that you use.

In `ProductService` I would return an observable, not a promise for two main reasons:

1. Observables are cancelable. So maybe a request takes a bit longer and the user changes it's mind, you want to be able to cancel that request and the server to stop processing it (if it's some intensive thing for the server).
2. Your service might evolve into pushing new items when something changes and promises can't do that. For example you have a generic repo service that has `items$` and some `add`/`delete` method. You might change the service to immediately update the items when `add`/`delete` works fine like in this example: [How do I add an item to an Observable<Entity[]> type from an API response, if the Observable is being handled by the async pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52722740/how-do-i-add-an-item-to-an-observableentity-type-from-an-api-response-if-th/52722970#52722970)